# How to share code & xib files between iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, architecture

I'm in the process of creating an app.  I'd like to have a pared down free version and a full paid version.  Obviously, they will share a lot of code and some xib files.  How to I share these without just duplicating them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a second target (duplicate the main one) for the light version. You can then remove any files as necessary and define a preprocessor macro if necessary to distinguish between code for the lite vs paid version within a given code file.

Comment: I'll second this. It's much easier to have two similar targets in one project than to manage two projects.

Answer (score 0):

How about making it one project with some sort of key or switch or something like that which will distinguish with version of the code to run.